# creating your own hashmap and hashtable

Tags: java

In a recent interview I was being asked how to write your own `HashMap`/`Hashtable` implementation in Java.

I have no idea of this so the only thing I said as a answer was that we can implement `HashMap` by using Array, because only this provides constant time access, if you know the index. Key is to writing hash function to minimize collision.

Can you please advise me how we can write our own `Hashmap`/`Hashtable`?

Comment: Here you go :) http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java. For hastable http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Hashtable.java

Comment: One of the first results when searching for "how to write a hash map":  http://whileonefork.blogspot.de/2011/02/hashmap-101-build-your-own.html

Comment: checkout [HashMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/HashMap.java) in java.

Comment: This is taught in every undergraduate data structures course, and described in every introductory data structure text book.

Comment: This is trending java question, Even I was asked the same question in one of the interview. The answer would be create a Entry class with key value just like  Entry<K,V>. Then add some implementation for methods such as get(key), put(key,value), remove(key). I found out an algorithm for custom HashMap may be it can help you. Check out the link : http://www.javamadesoeasy.com/2015/02/hashmap-custom-implementation.html

Answer (score 6):

Look sources to get more about how do they work.

- [`java.util.Hashtable`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Hashtable.java.html)
- [`java.util.HashMap`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html)

Also, there are some good explanations at SO:

- [How does a Java HashMap handle different objects with the same hash code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493605/how-does-java-hashmap-work)
- [Hash : How does it work internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453476/hash-how-does-it-work-internally)
- [Hashtable. How it works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975673/hashtable-how-it-works)
- [How does a hash table work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730620/how-does-a-hash-table-work)

Comment: This is trending java question, Even I was asked the same question in one of the interview. The answer would be create a Entry class with key value just like  Entry<K,V>. Then add some implementation for methods such as get(key), put(key,value), remove(key). I found out an algorithm for custom HashMap may be it can help you. Check out the link :